# What is the replication logic for Cluster mode enabled in Elasticache Redis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster

I have a Redis cluster with **cluster mode enabled** and 3 nodes (1 master and 2 replicas). I have noticed that the CPU percentage of one of the replicas is similar to the master node while that of the other replica remains quite low. So, what is the replication logic at play here? Is it like only one replica is used to replicate data proactively and the other one is used only after the first one fails?
PFA screenshot of the CPU percentage usage over a week
PS: The application connects to the cluster using `Configuration Endpoint`

[image: CPU Usage]

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Endpoints.html),

> Redis (cluster mode disabled) clusters, use the Primary Endpoint for all write operations. Use the Reader Endpoint to **evenly split incoming** connections to the endpoint between all read replicas. Use the individual Node Endpoints for read operations (In the API/CLI these are referred to as Read Endpoints).

If you use the reader endpoint it will split the load evenly.

As it is stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Replication.Redis.Groups.html)

> Each read replica maintains a copy of the data from the cluster's primary node. Asynchronous replication mechanisms are used to keep the read replicas synchronized with the primary.

My optimistic guess is that; instead of reader endpoint, your application directly reads from the single replica. Maybe the endpoint(higher cpu) is hardcoded within the application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got my question all wrong and your answer made me realise that. The Redis cluster is running with Cluster Mode Enabled and how I found it out was it has a `Configuration Endpoint` which is found only for Cluster Mode Enabled. What confused me was the fact that the cluster has only 1 shard which is inherent to Cluster Mode disabled.

I will go ahead and edit my question